# Empty scrollbar appears with no overflow

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, scrollbar, overflow

### I want to know if there's a clean way to "reset" the scrollbar.

In the series of images below, you can see how the same-sized body and HTML differ by having a scroll bar and not.

Interestingly, the scrollbar is not present in the final image, just the region where the scrollbar scrolled persists.

I'd prefer to not set a max-height attribute of 599px to avoid the overflow. I'm looking to anyone who's seen this bug and knows of a nice way to reset the scrollbar area.

#### 1. The first image is expanding the chrome extension to its maximum 600px height.

[image: Initial Display (no overflow)]

#### 2. The second image is expanding the tables to overflow the 600px height, producing a scroll bar.

[image: Extend table for overflow]

#### 3. The third image is collapsing the table and reverting the display to the original 600px height; however, now there exists an empty "scroll field"?

[image: Collapse table but overflow appears]

Comment: I'm wondering if this is some round-off error with the DOM... I can't find any records of a bug like this occurring, so I'm interested to see what others think.

Comment: not an answer but for blink and webkit browsers you can create an invisible scrollbar by `::-webkit-scrollbar{ display:none; }`

Comment: @lastr2d2 your comment actually inspired me to try force refreshing certain elements by changing their properties. For some reason, hidden overflows do not fix the issue, but setting the overflow to either auto or overlay temporarily and then reverting back to the other display will refresh the element. I'll post more in my answer, but thanks for your comment, it helped me.

Comment: glad it helped in some way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using requestAnimationFrame — *Updated*

By using [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), the scrollbar is refreshed exactly on the DOM repaint:

```js
function scrollRefresh(element) {
    // initial overflow attribute
    element.style.overflow = "auto";
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        // final overflow attribute
        element.style.overflow = "overlay";
    });
}
```

A benefit of using requestAnimationFrame is the scrollbar never changes to the user; instead, the DOM repaints it seemlessly. This method is much more smooth and efficient than the setTimeout() alternative.

---

---

### Using setTimeout

A function that forces the DOM to refresh the scrollbar will work:

```js
function scrollRefresh(element) {
    // initial overflow attribute
    element.style.overflow = "auto";
    setTimeout(() => {
        // final overflow attribute
        element.style.overflow = "overlay";
    }, 17); // 17 ms timeout
}
```

Two things of note in this solution:

1. The overflow switching must include the `auto` overflow attribute. Beginning with `auto` or `overlay` does not matter; it is, however, necessary that the final overflow attribute is different from the initial.
2. The timeout is proportional to success. A timeout of `0 ms` won't work, while a timeout of `5 ms` will work around 30%. A timeout of `20 ms` worked consistently for me.

I believe the timeout is related to the DOM refresh rate. From a quick [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Frame_Timing_API/Using_the_Frame_Timing_API), it's around `60 fps` (or `16.6̅ ms`), so a `20 ms` is more than enough. A timeout of `17 ms` should refresh slowly enough for the DOM to always render the overflow change.

---

---

Here's a [demonstration](https://github.com/splch/writest/blob/5b1c5663cc7baa9e6aff5512b06ed0b1bdb6cb28/scripts/popup.js#L5) of the function working:

[image: working overflow refresh]

I want to thank @lastr2d2 for their comment, as it helped me find a solution.